# How to bind data coming from dataset to header in rdlc reports?

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Expected:
I need to get values coming from the dataset to put them in the header.

I've done some work around:
-Create textboxs in the body area, populate them with the correct values coming from dataset. Get the values from the Header like this:
ReportItems!txtFromBody.Value

No luck! The header is filled out with the correct information in the last page only.

I thought maybe I can use parameters, not sure at this point.
Need some help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use parameter for header.
[image]

Now add parameter

```
// Add Parameter 
            List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("AccountName", accountName));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("AccountCode", "Account Code: " + accountCode));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("UnitName", unitName.ToUpper()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("UnitAddress", unitAddress.ToUpper()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Title", "Schedule"));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Date", dateVal));
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
            ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            ReportViewer1.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you are using. In VS2010, you can bind data to header without problem.